# How to get creation date from word file if Last print date does not exist?

Tags: c#, ole

I am trying to get last print date of word files which implemented using the following code. The code works fine if the last print date field is not empty. If it is empty it gives an error. How can I get creation date from word file if Last print date does not exist?

```
     object oDocAuthorProp = typeDocBuiltInProps.InvokeMember("Item", 
                          BindingFlags.Default | 
                          BindingFlags.GetProperty, 
                          null,oDocBuiltInProps, 
                          new object[] {"Last Print Date"} );

      Type typeDocAuthorProp = oDocAuthorProp.GetType();
   strValue = typeDocAuthorProp.InvokeMember("Value",
                              BindingFlags.Default |
                              BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                              null, oDocAuthorProp,
                              new object[] { }).ToString();
```

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation

Answer (score 0):

One way is to first check for the error, and if it occurs use the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class to access the file's [`CreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication56
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"Your file path here");
            Console.WriteLine(fi.CreationTime);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 1000 doc files waiting for sorting and I don't know how many of them missing last print date

Comment: That is why I said you need to **check** for the condition that has the error, I am assuming that you do know the path of your file. Is the error thrown in the first part of your code or the second?